# How to ill a bidimensional array with the distance value from center?

Tags: c#, arrays, trigonometry

I know from school this formula to know if a point is outside a radius of a 2d array, but I don't get how to modify that to fill an array instead of checking, with the distance value (circular not squared) from the center, more or less like the array below

```
if ((z * z + x * x) > (radius * radius))
                {
                    array[i] = value;
                }

this is the array I want to get, but I'm not sure if tis is the formula to start with

5 - 5 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 5 - 5
5 - 4 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 4 - 5
4 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 4
4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4
4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4
4 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 4
5 - 4 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 4 - 5
5 - 5 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 5 - 5
```

Comment: I don’t see a bidimensional array in your code. If `radius` is your array height and width `array` should have been declared as `var array = new int[radius, radius];` and accessed via `array[y, x]`.

Comment: The question wasn't how to declare an array, but how to populate it (even widt and length) with the values on the array underneath

Comment: Like I wrote you asked about a bidimensional array, but didn’t even use one in your code. So is your question about bidimensional arrays or not? If yes, why is your code using a unidimensional array? Generally speaking, if you want to map a bidimensional array to an unidimensional one the index is `i = y * radius + x`. If the array bounds do not start at (0, 0) like in your case you need to add this to your x and y offsets, i.e. `i = (y + radius / 2) * radius + (x + radius / 2)`.